Display a grid within blazor's default <article>@Body</article> that fills & scrolls the entire <article> area
Within a Blazor app, I would like to display a grid that fills the entire
<article>
@Body
</article> area.
I've tried a few variations of
<container>
    <row>
        <col>
            <grid>
        </col>
    </row>
</container>

however the grid (Radzen or DevExpress in this case) never full fills the entire  area.
Example:
<div class="container p-0 m-0 pe-0 me-0" style="width:100%">
    <div class="row" style="width:100%">
        <div class="col-xxl12" style="width:100%">
            <RadzenDataGrid .../>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

And here is what I see when inspecting the article element on the rendered page (note the empty area to the left of the grid):

Note <container> does not fill <article>

I have also tried using the <container-fluid> tag which does cause the grid to display but the scrollbar is displayed for the entire browser page, not only the area within the <article> tags, which is not the desired behavior.
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <RadzenDataGrid .../>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Note the scroll bar across the entire browser:

CSS is still a bit new for me and I'm fairly confident that by using some CSS kung-fu the desired outcome can be achieved.

If your using the standard template the padding come from two places:
MainLayout.razor.css - line 74.
    .top-row, article {
        padding-left: 2rem !important;
        padding-right: 1.5rem !important;

And if that's removed then the padding set directly on article:
MainLayout.razor - line 13.
        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>

You need to make the necessary adjustments in both places.  Be carefully of media widths as the MainLayout.razor.css style only applies to @media (min-width: 641px).
Personally I would use a different layout for the pages you want the padding removed.
